# Purpose of 47R resistor in USB interface

Tags: usb, attiny, resistors

I was making a simple circuit to directly connect the ATTiny85 to a laptop with USB. What is the purpose of the 47R resistors in this? What effect can these resistors have with such little resistance?

[image: schematic]

Source: https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/attiny85-ic-programming-through-usb-using-digispark-bootloader

Comment: I dunno. It's basically the digispark interface. It's probably better asked on ESE,  but then, it probably has been. By the way, D2 is backwards.

Comment: Probably an attempt at line termination. I don't think it makes sense tho, the MCU will have much higher input impedance and sufficiently high output impedance I guess.

Comment: Heh, someone deleted the comment I was replying to so half of it looks kind of nuts now. In case anybody was wondering the "I dunno" part was about whether or not it could have been considered on topic for ASE.

Comment: The resistors are a best-effort attempt to implement something close to USB driver specification of having 45 Ohm driver impedance at 3V amplitude,  out of the 5-V driver circuits. They are perfectly fine and do not exceed any IO ratings because they never drive HIGH at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation is simple but long.

They hopefully prevent the makeshift USB connection from frying your expensive PC with your cheap AVR.

While other answers say that they are for matching impedance, it is hard to believe that is the real reason, as it would be too sophisticated reason for this shady USB interface that barely works anyway, and can potentially damage your PC or MCU if anything goes wrong. The parts are simply needed for bare minimum level conversion and clamping to prevent damage.

The resistors are there because the AVR needs to be powered by 5V to run fast enough to implement USB protocol in software.

It means that the GPIO pins use 5V voltage levels. But that is too high for USB interface as it uses 3.3V levels.

Therefore the USB data lines have a Zener diode to clamp the voltage to 3.3V, so the 5V signal from AVR does not fry your expensive PC.

But Zeners need to pass a lot of current, as much AVR can possibly output when 5V signal is externally limited to 3.3V. So to prevent the Zeners and the AVR pins from getting fried, current-limiting resistors are placed between 5V AVR output side, and 3.3V PC side.

In theory, the resistors limit the current from AVR output to 36mA per pin.

Now, that is very close to absolute maximum rating of 40mA per AVR pin, and will exceed the safe rating of total 60mA limit per all IO ports for the AVR.

So while that is a neat trick, I don't recommend using it due to the dangers, as MCUs with real USB interface have been available for a long time now.

Comment: Re: *"and will exceed the safe rating of total 60mA limit per all IO ports for the AVR*" I'm not sure where you're getting 60mA from. There's a 200mA limit for the ATTiny85. Upvoting for the rest.

Comment: @timemage Just do a search on the datasheet. 200mA is absolute maximum for supply pins.The next page says sum for all ports "should not exceed 60 mA".

Comment: Ah, you're talking about current limit (IOH) beyond which you can't meet the VOH spec, I guess. Anyway, if not I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @timemage No, I am not talking about that.